# Change field names in a Django query

Tags: sql, django, django-models, field

I have several Django queries which I need to combine with `.union()`.

But `.union()` works only if all the fields names are the same, what is not the case.

So, how to modify field names in Django queries (like using `AS` keyword in SQL)?

Comment: Given your other question, you might find [this blog post](https://simonwillison.net/2018/Mar/25/combined-recent-additions/) by Django co-creator Simon Willison useful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `annotate()` to add a new field to each item in the queryset. Then use `values()` so that you only return the columns you want in the union.

```
MyModel.objects.annotate(new_name=F('old_name').values('new_name', 'other_field').union(
    MyOtherModel.objects.annotate(new_name=F('other_old_name').values('new_name', 'other_field')
)
```